# Plain text emails are not shown correctly in Outlook

Tags: java, spring, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I am sending plain text emails from Java Spring application

```
MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
// Sets the text
mimeMessageHelper.setText(emailBodyAsPlainText, false);
```

**Actual text sent:** 
  
    User Name                        : User 1

User ID                              : user1

**Text shown in email:**

User Name                            : User 1

User ID                       : user1

I have included spaces between the label and value. If we observe the actual text the colons are aligned properly. But in email these are misaligned and the space between the lable and values is not consistent.

It looks like Out look is doing some custom formatting.

Please advise how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Put the rows and columns with your data into an HTML table and send your messages in the HTML format.